# wget working on linux but not on mac os

Tags: linux, macos, wget

I'm trying to download this file: `http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_megase.zip` using wget, like this:

```
wget http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_megase.zip
```

because the server uses a cookie check this makes 2 different requests to the same url, the first return a 302 and the second the actual data.

On my vps running linux this works, but on my development machine, a mac os 10.9.5 it doesn't.

This is the output for `wget http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_megase.zip`:

On my Mac:

```
--2015-01-12 15:22:47--  http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_megase.zip
Resolvendo www1.caixa.gov.br (www1.caixa.gov.br)... 200.201.160.210
Conectando-se a www1.caixa.gov.br (www1.caixa.gov.br)|200.201.160.210|:80... conectado.
A requisição HTTP foi enviada, aguardando resposta... 302 Found
Localização: http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_megase.zip [redirecionando]
--2015-01-12 15:22:48--  http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_megase.zip
Conectando-se a www1.caixa.gov.br (www1.caixa.gov.br)|200.201.160.210|:80... conectado.
A requisição HTTP foi enviada, aguardando resposta... 404 Not Found
2015-01-12 15:22:49 ERRO 404: Not Found.
```

On my VPS:

```
--2015-01-12 17:23:43--  http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_megase.zip
Resolving www1.caixa.gov.br (www1.caixa.gov.br)... 200.201.160.210
Connecting to www1.caixa.gov.br (www1.caixa.gov.br)|200.201.160.210|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_megase.zip [following]
--2015-01-12 17:23:44--  http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_megase.zip
Connecting to www1.caixa.gov.br (www1.caixa.gov.br)|200.201.160.210|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 100675 (98K) [application/x-zip-compressed]
Saving to: 'D_megase.zip.5'

100%[===========================================================================================================================================>] 100,675      142KB/s   in 0.7s

2015-01-12 17:23:45 (142 KB/s) - 'D_megase.zip.5' saved [100675/100675]
```

Can anyone help me?

this it the output with debug: https://gist.github.com/NicosKaralis/4407d59e8d0c620fdcbd you clearly can see that the requests are the same and the response don't have anything different

Comment: Did you try with `wget --retry-connrefused ...` or better with `wget --content-on-error ...` ?

Comment: Just tried, ``--retry-connrefused`` still get the 404 error and doesn't save anything, ``--content-on-error`` still get the 404 but the 404 html provided by the server is saved on the output file

Comment: I'm sorry I've no _mac_ to test it. Did you try both options together? With pure Linux and GNU wget v 1.15 it works with no need of option. It seems that on the _osx system_ you have the same version (!). If forced you can try to download and compile it from  the source code, maybe as a new command and with `--static` option. Moreover it seems it exists at least a newer version of _wget_ for mac (1.16). You can try `curl -L http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_megase.zip
 -o ./D_megase.zip`

Comment: ``curl -L`` gives me this: `curl: (47) Maximum (50) redirects followed`, but if I pass `-H 'Cookie: security=true'` it appears to stop the redirects but the behavior is too much erratic, like 10 requests made and 7 404 errors on mac and 8 on my linux vps, is there a way to check if they block my IP or something?

Comment: I was thinking something similar... try to find a file that give no errors or, better, try to use a proxy from your _mac_; better if from the same VPN. However __if you use the same proxy from both machines__ (_mac_ and _VPN-Linux_) you can see if it is a problem of different versions for `wget` or if it is a problem of IP blocked.

Comment: i'll try and come back later